# Relationship between two Normal Random Variables with covariance matrices that are inverse of each other

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

Let $$x_1 \sim N(0, \Sigma_1)$$ $$x_2 \sim N(0, \Sigma_2)$$ $$\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2^{-1}$$

That is each covariance matrix can be seen as the precision matrix (or inverse) of the other.

**Simple question:** What is the relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$?

**Edit:** I am looking for relationships that suggest a solution to the following question – If I can sample $x_1$ can I use this to efficiently sample $x_2$? I am happy if it ends up being an approximation to samples of $x_2$. (By efficiently I mean something faster than using Cholesky factors).

Comment: Both of them follow normal distribution with mean 0; $Var(X_1) = 1/Var(x_2)$.

Comment: Is that a joke? That's pretty much the definition of the question :).

Comment: Not joke. based on provided information, if you add any additional description, it will be wrong.

Comment: I suspect it is nothing special.  You should do the following: examine the joint distribution of x_1 and x_2. There are theorems which let you express the covariance matrix of the joint distribution in terms of the marginal covariance matrices.  Do that, take a look if any interesting structure appears.

Comment: About distribution of $1/X$ given $X\sim Normal$, you can do s tiny simulation. I am sure it is not normal distributed.

Comment: @DemetriP I think the covariance matrix just mean the variance because $x$ is random variable, instead of random vector based on $x_1=1/x_2$ is used.

Comment: @a_statistician it is clear OP is asking about random vectors rather than random variables.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about random vectors (a form of a random variable). No the distribution of 1/X is not normal its called a reciprocal normal.

Comment: Edit to question should give more info about my motivation in asking this question.

Comment: Do you know anything about $\Sigma_{12}$?

Comment: @MossMurderer No. The key question is how to sample $x_2$ given $x_1$.

Comment: To sample $x_2$ given $x_1$, you need to construct $P(x_2|x_1)$. And for this, you need to know $\Sigma_{12}$.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity of notation, consider 2-vectors of random variables and also that that the random variables comprising $\mathbf X_1$ are *standard* normal random variables.  Then, the assumption is that $\mathbf X_1$ and $\mathbf X_2$ are pairs of jointly normal random variables with covariance matrices
$$\Sigma_1 = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & \rho\\\rho & 1\end{matrix}\right]\quad \text{and}\quad\Sigma_2 = \Sigma_1^{-1} = \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{1-\rho^2} & \frac{-\rho}{1-\rho^2}\\\frac{-\rho}{1-\rho^2} & \frac{1}{1-\rho^2}\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}\sigma^2 & -\rho\sigma^2\\-\rho\sigma^2 & \sigma^2\end{matrix}\right]$$
respectively where $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{1-\rho^2} \geq 1$.  So we see immediately that the random variables in $\mathbf X_2$ have larger variances than those in $\mathbf X_1$ and also the correlation coefficient between them has the same magnitude as the correlation coefficient between the random variables in $\mathbf X_1$ *but the opposite sign!*

If the random variables have different means and/or variances, the results are messier, and of course for vector random variables of larger dimensions, even simple observations such as those made above are more difficult.

---

Returning to the case of 2-vectors, my interpretation of what the OP calls "the key question" is that of constructing *samples* of $\mathbf X_2$ given that we have available to us some *samples* of $\mathbf X_1$.  That is, we are given $n$ pairs of real numbers (the $n$ known samples of $\mathbf X_1$) and asked what samples of $\mathbf X_2$ might look like. This is easy: from the results $\operatorname{cov}(X,-Y) = -\operatorname{cov}(X,Y),  \operatorname{var}(aX)=a^2\operatorname{var}(X)$, we have that if $\mathbf X_1 = (X_1,Y_1)$ is a pair of standard (jointly) normal random variables with covariance (and correlation coefficient) $\rho$), that is,  $\mathbf X_1 \sim N(0,\Sigma_1)$, then $(\sigma X_1, -\sigma Y_1)$ is a pair of zero-mean jointly normal random variables with variance $\sigma^2$ and covariance $-\rho\sigma^2$, that is $\mathbf X_1\sim N(0,\Sigma_2)$. Thus, if we have $n$ samples $(x_i,y_i), 1 \leq i \leq n,$ of $\mathbf X_1$, then we can take
$(\sigma x_i, -\sigma y_i), 1 \leq i \leq n$ to be $n$ samples of $\mathbf X_2 \sim N(0, \Sigma_2)$.

Hey, it is not possible to make a silk purse out of a sow's ear. Nobody said that samples of $\mathbf X_2$ have to be independent of the samples of $\mathbf X_1$, and if we are *constructing* samples of $\mathbf X_2$ from samples of $\mathbf X_1$ without any random or pseudorandom *deux ex machina*, then there has to be some connection between the samples, right? And if we *are* bringing in randomness, then just sample directly from $\mathbf X_2$ and be done with it. Why bring in samples of $\mathbf X_1$ into the picture at all?

Comment: This is nice. Does this suggest a general means of sampling $x_2$ given $x_1$? (See bottom of question)

Comment: @jds. See addendum to my answer.

Comment: You are right, no reason samples of $X_2$ have to be independent of samples of $X_1$. The difficulty with sampling from $X_2$ directly is inverting the covariance. Your answer works for your special case of 2 dimensions and this very restricted covariance structure. It is however of minimal use in the general case.